# Why can't I target Mono in VS2010 on Windows?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mono

I have downloaded and installed the Mono framework onto my Win7 development machine.  I then followed the instructions [here](http://ralch.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-use-mono-on-visual-studio-2010/) to have Visual Studio 2010 allow targeting of the Mono framework instead of .NET.  I then create this test console app using VB with the target framwework set "Mono 2.10.8 profile" in the project's Advanced Compile Options:

```
Dim runningOnMono As Boolean = Not IsNothing(Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime"))
Console.WriteLine("Running on Mono =  " & runningOnMono.ToString)
```

When I run this on the Win7 dev machine it returns False i.e. not running on Mono.  When I run the program on a Linux machine that only has Mono installalled it returns True.

I can reference parts of the Mono framework in VS and intellisense works, but when I make this call:

```
Dim monoinf As New Mono.Unix.UnixDriveInfo("g:")
```

I get this exception:

===================================

FileNotFoundException was unhandled:  Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

===================================

Mono.Posix.dll version 4.0.0.0 ***does*** exist in many directories including the one created specifically for the VS Mono profile.  I even tried copying it to the test app's directory.

Is it just that my mono install on the Win7 box is a mess?  How can it be that intellisense works but the call to Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") returns Nothing ?

The resaon I am trying to target Mono is because the class System.IO.DriveInfo does not work on Mono so I think I have to use Mono.Unix.UnixDriveInfo if I want to run on Windows and Linux.  I need to get the free space of a USB flash drive.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already target Mono by following the blog post, but you should use mono.exe to launch your executable (test.exe as example) at Mono command prompt,

`mono.exe test.exe`

That's the only way Mono runtime is loaded instead of .NET Framework on Windows.